# Displaying an image resource with PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to simply get a test image, crop it a bit, and display it. The thing is, I am doing this from PHP, and every attempt I have made thus far has frustrated me even more; /* and the internet is telling me to do things that I have already done. */

**OK, so what have you done??**

I have tried various ways of getting the `$image` itself. I have tried the following:

1. Using `imagecreatefromstring($url);` /* where `$url` is the location of the image (I am pulling from random sites, which is a necessity for my project */
2. Using `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));` and then, in a `<div>` tag, echoing the image
3. Using `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));` and then, in an `<img>` tag, echoing the image
4. Doing 3., except using `imagejpeg($image)`
5. Doing 4., except, this time, putting `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

**OK, what happened?**

First attempt returned a nice error saying that `$image` was not recognized.
Second attempt seems to work, but instead of an image, I get back the following text: `Resource id #5`
Third attempt gives me a bunch of gibberish.
Fourth attempt also gave me a bunch of gibberish.
Fifth attempt gave me a black screen with this error message: `The image “http://localhost/ResearchProject/sampleImageDisplay.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`

Here is the final code (and header.php just contains all of the necessary HTML tags to display the web page (the DOCTYPE tag, the html tag, the meta tag...) ):

```
<?php
    include "header.php";

    $url = "http://byebyedoctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/alopecia-areata-3.jpg";
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
?>
        <img>
            <?php header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  imagejpeg($image); ?>
        </img>
        <?php imagedestroy($image); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why can't I display this simple image??

Comment: Please read the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php . Is not that the "GD" works and you're not doing error handling.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is returning a string.

Comment: You don't understand... you forgot to do error handling, that's not how it works. Just a tip. :)

Comment: How would I do error handling in this case?

Comment: If you want to send image data to the browser, then you have to send _only_ image data to the browser; and not HTML code around it. Your approach #1 is obviously nonsense, that should have been clear to you if you’d understood what that function does. The approaches that get you “gibberish” are good, they just need a Content-Type header so that the browser knows how to handle the data it receives. But with attempt #5 of course you get an error, because the output will contain PHP warnings about using `header` after output has already been send (your nonsense HTML tags).

Comment: Ok, you read doc? No? Yes? Ok... tomorrow I'll have time and post a answer (I'm on iPhone).    Good luck in your project

Comment: Also, I made sure that the URL was a URL to an actual image, and that it didn't return FALSE ! In addition, I already included the header! What more do I have to do?

Comment: _“What more do I have to do?”_ – you need to realize that images don’t contain HTML tags …

Comment: Here is my updated code, after trying everything that I was told here: http://pastebin.com/ik4VbRTh

Comment: Fine, now go read the manual and find out what type of first parameter the function `imageJPEG` expects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code worked for me. Just create empty php file and paste this code. It should return the photo of a semi-bold man.

```
$url = "http://byebyedoctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/alopecia-areata-3.jpg";
$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));

if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

Comment: This works! I guess I was expecting too much; /* I was expecting a way to display an image inside an HTML element. Namely, I was expecting to get an image from a website, crop it to fit, and display it inside a div/img element. They should fill in here: http://imgur.com/diVPe7m */

Comment: @Dejan: And you are base64 encoding the image data only to base64 decode it again immediately afterwards because otherwise the CPU gets bored … or what?

Comment: @CBroe Yes that's exactly what I do! You first need to properly encode the picture to the base64 format and then properly decode it. Without first encoding the resourse this wouldn't work.

Comment: @MikeWarren You could try to put this code in a separate php file and then call that php file in javascript with ajax call.

Comment: _“You first need to properly encode the picture to the base64 format and then properly decode it. Without first encoding the resourse this wouldn't work.”_ – that is, of course, total nonsense.

Comment: Also, you are reading the image twice from the URL, for no good reason either. Looks like this rather “works” by accident, and not because you’d really know what you are doing, sorry.

Comment: @CBroe I do realise this is not the best solution but it works. If you have a better idea how to implement this please tell us.

Comment: You can simply remove lines 4 to 7 (and change variable name in line 2 to `$im`), and it should work absolutely the same.

Comment: @CBroe After considering your comments I did some more research on the documentation and played with the code and I realised what you meant by "total nonsense" and I agree with you. Thank you for pointing this. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off...

You have to make sure that "allow_url_fopen" is enabled in php.ini.

If you have access to this file just change

```
;allow_url_fopen
```

To

```
allow_url_fopen
```

Some hosts disable access to php.ini though.

Then all you have to do is this....

```
$url = "http://byebyedoctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/alopecia-areata-3.jpg";
$image = file_get_contents($url);
```

Then you can store it temporarily to resize it or whatever...

```
//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen("/location/to/save/tempimage.jpg", "w");
fwrite($fp, $image);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Also, does it **have** to be saved, in order to manipulate it and display it??

Comment: In addition, how do I **display** it? Should I use one of those image-casting functions?! This is what I was asking!

Comment: No you dont have to, if you do it the way you were doing it above, but you have to make sure gd extension is enabled   extension=php_gd.dll  in php.ini

Comment: Does it have to be a gd ?

Comment: And when you use this imagejpeg($image) make sure its imageJPEG($image)  thats the correct function call

Comment: `extension=php_gd.dll` is not found in my php.ini file, but `extension=php_gd2.dll` was. Yes, it is not commented-out.

Answer (score 0):

Your major planning problem is: You try to include you image into a html code.
For this you need 2 phps:

1. A php file what contains your html-code with an img-tag (src must be the second php-file)
2. A php file what reads you base image and outputs the **BINARY** image data

**your_htmlpage.php**

```
<html>
   <?php
        include "header.php";
   ?>
   <body>
        <img src="your_image.php">
   </body>
</html>
```

**your_image.php**

```
<?php
  $url = "http://byebyedoctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/alopecia-areata-3.jpg";
  $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
  if($image !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
  } else {
    header("X-Error", true, 404);

    echo "Error loading remote image";
  }

  ?>
```

Another option would be to send the image as base64encoded String to the browser. But this means that the WHOLE image-data is part of the html-code. 
e.g. lik this:

```
<html>
   <?php
        include "header.php";


        $url = "http://byebyedoctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/alopecia-areata-3.jpg";
        $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
        if($image !== false) {
          // start buffering and catch image output
          ob_start();
          imagejpg($image);
          $contents =  ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
          imagedestroy($image);

          $img_data = "data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($contents);
        } else {
          $img_data = "";
        }
   ?>
   <body>
        <img src="<?php echo $img_data; ?>">
   </body>
</html>
```